# Sublime text regex find/replace within XML

Tags: regex, xml, sublimetext3

I'm altering a communication-aid language-pack for a disabled learner. She needs all the cells to be 'speaknow' rather than 'type', with an additional parameter. All the commands are contained within multiple xml files. I need to match all the commands -> command -> type and change them.

Example:

```
...
<commands>
    <command>
        <id>type</id>
        <parameter index="1"><![CDATA[Good Afternoon ]]></parameter>
    </command>
</commands>
...
```

to

```
...
<commands>
    <command>
        <id>speaknow</id>
        <parameter index="1"><![CDATA[Good Afternoon ]]></parameter>
        <parameter index="2"><![CDATA[1]]></parameter>
    </command>
</commands>
...
```

bearing in mind "Good Afternoon " is different in each cell.

Is Regex in Sublime Text the way to go (and if so how?), or is there a better method for multiple XML files.

Many thanks

Comment: You could record a macro and replay it in sublime, however you'll need to do this for every `command` block

Comment: This SO is what saved me here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13241658/826308

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sublime macros](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-banish-repetitive-tasks-with-sublime-text-2-macros--webdesign-6398). you'll need to replay your macro in each `command` xml block.

Another option that I'd recommend if you are dealing with a number of files is to write a xslt transform file.

Take a look at this example: http://xsltransform.net/gWvjQeU

Comment: xsltransform looks good! Any idea why it's escaping <![CDATA[.]]> though??