# Replace string using pattern in XML string in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql

I would like to replace span tags from XML string using regex from multiple records in a column of type string.

Looking for how to remove starting span tags for Ex: `"<span class="TAGGED_ITEM " id="c1_ae1">"`

Will be able to replace `"</span>"` with Empty string.

Here is the Input.

```
    <Item title="1234" xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p2">
        <ItemBody>
        <div class="item_text">
                        <div>
                            <span class="TAGGED_ITEM " id="c1_ae1">This is a map on a grid.</span>
                            <span class="TAGGED_ITEM " id="c1_ae2"> It shows a car.</span>
                        </div>
                            <span class="TAGGED_ITEM " id="c1_ae3"> It shows a car on Road.</span>
                    </div>
        </ItemBody>
    </Item>
```

Here is output.

```
  <Item title="1234" xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p2">
        <ItemBody>
        <div class="item_text">
                        <div>
                            This is a map on a grid.
                             It shows a car.
                        </div>
                           It shows a car on Road.
                    </div>
        </ItemBody>
    </Item>
```

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Comment: Have a look here..  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13241658/175063

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex to replace span tag with empty string

```
<span.+?>|<\/span>
```

For your Input the above regex select span tag :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to replace your span tags, this should do it for you.

```
<span class[^>]*>|<\/span>
```

have a look here: [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lJ6kP7/1)