# Sentence case a passage of text while ignoring html elements within

Tags: javascript, regex

At the moment I am passing a passage of text to the following function, in order to make sure that the first letter of each sentence is capitalised.

```
function sentenceCase(string) {
    var n = string.split(".");
    var vfinal = ""
    for (i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        var spaceput = ""
        var spaceCount = n[i].replace(/^(\s*).*$/, "$1").length;
        n[i] = n[i].replace(/^\s+/, "");
        var newstring = n[i].charAt(n[i]).toUpperCase() + n[i].slice(1);
        for (j = 0; j < spaceCount; j++) spaceput = spaceput + " ";
        vfinal = vfinal + spaceput + newstring + ".";
    }
    vfinal = vfinal.substring(0, vfinal.length - 1);
    return vfinal;
}
```

This works well when the text doesn't contain any elements, and everything is uppercased as it should be.

```
var str1 = 'he always has a positive contribution to make to the class. in class, he behaves well, but he should aim to complete his homework a little more regularly.';
console.log(sentenceCase(str1));

Returns >>> He always has a positive contribution to make to the class. In class, he behaves well, but he should aim to complete his homework a little more regularly.
```

However if the text contains a `<span>` element wrapping the first word in the sentence, then it obviously causes problems, as shown.

```
var str2 = '<span class="pronoun subjective">he</span> always has a positive contribution to make to the class. in class, <span class="pronoun subjective">he</span> behaves well, but <span class="pronoun subjective">he</span> should aim to complete <span class="pronoun possessive">his</span> homework a little more regularly.'; 
console.log(sentenceCase(str2));

Returns >>> <span class="pronoun subjective">he</span> always has a positive contribution to make to the class. In class, <span class="pronoun subjective">he</span> behaves well, but <span class="pronoun subjective">he</span> should aim to complete <span class="pronoun possessive">his</span> homework a little more regularly.
```

My regex skills are far from stellar so I'm not sure how to proceed from here, so any suggestions on how to ignore any elements in the text when converting it to sentence case would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: To clarify - the output should still maintain the  elements - they just need to be ignored when considering the sentence for upper-casing.

Comment: your output should contain HTML element or it should be removed like you are looking for <span..> He </span>... or just He .........

Comment: You can sanitise the string before passing it to the function:  
`string = string.replace(/<.*?>/g, '');`  This removes the HTML tags.

Comment: Sorry - to clarify - the output should still maintain the <span> elements - they just need to be ignored when considering the sentence for upper-casing.

Comment: regex is not the right tool for this. https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/

Comment: @Ouroborus: To be sure, regexp is still the fantastic tool for *parts* of this.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a trivial problem. Doing it purely with regexp is [bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241615/find-everything-between-two-xml-tags-with-regex) because you can get into hairy corner cases and mess up things - JS regexp is simply not powerful enough to deal with full HTML syntax.

However, a browser already has a way of dealing with HTML.

```js
var str2 = '<span class="pronoun subjective">he</span> always has a positive contribution to make to the class. in class, <span class="pronoun subjective">he</span> behaves well, but <span class="pronoun subjective">he</span> should aim to complete <span class="pronoun possessive">his</span> homework a little more regularly.';

function capitalise(html) {
  // HTML DOM parser: engage!
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = html;

  // assume the start of the string is also a start of a sentence
  var boundary = true;

  // go through every text node
  var walker = document.createTreeWalker(div, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, true);
  while (walker.nextNode()) {
    var node = walker.currentNode;
    var text = node.textContent;

    // if we are between sentences, capitalise the first letter
    if (boundary) {
      text = text.replace(/[a-z]/, function(letter) {
        return letter.toUpperCase();
      });
    }

    // capitalise for any internal punctuation
    text = text.replace(/([.?!]\s+)([a-z])/g, function(_, punct, letter) {
      return punct + letter.toUpperCase();
    });

    // If the current node ends in punctuation, we're back at sentence boundary
    boundary = text.match(/[.?!]\s*$/);

    // change the current node's text
    node.textContent = text;
  }
  return div.innerHTML;
}

console.log(capitalise(str2));
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach - if the split starts with `<`, find the first letter following a closing `>`, and replace it with a capital letter.  This works even if there are multiple tags.

```js
var string = '<span class="pronoun subjective"><strong = ">95">he</strong></span> always has a positive contribution to make to the class. in class, <span class="pronoun subjective">he</span> behaves well, but <span class="pronoun subjective">he</span> should aim to complete. <span class="pronoun possessive">his</span> homework a little more regularly.';
var n = string.split(".");
var vfinal = ""
for (i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
  var spaceput = ""
  var spaceCount = n[i].replace(/^(\s*).*$/, "$1").length;
  if (n[i].trim().charAt(0) == '<') {
    var first = n[i].match(/"?>([a-zA-Z])/)[1];
    var firstCap = first.toUpperCase();
    var newstring = n[i].replace(first, firstCap);
  } else {
    n[i] = n[i].replace(/^\s+/, "");
    var newstring = n[i].charAt(n[i]).toUpperCase() + n[i].slice(1);
  }
  for (j = 0; j < spaceCount; j++) spaceput = spaceput + " ";
  vfinal = vfinal + spaceput + newstring + ".";
}
vfinal = vfinal.substring(0, vfinal.length - 1);
console.log(vfinal);
```

Comment: Won't work for `<span data-certainty=">95%">this</span> doesn't work.`. Getting regexp to do this correctly is non-trivial.

Comment: Fair call.  Updated to allow for a closing `>` or `">`  This is probably not an ideal solution, but if the input is consistent and predictable, then perhaps a simpler approach can work.