# Regular Expression for matching XML nodes

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have a series of repeating XML tags represented in a String:

```
<Field name="foo" date="20170501">
   <Value type="foo">someVal</Value>
</Field>
<Field name="foo" date="20170501">
   <Value type="foo">someVal</Value>
</Field>
```

I am trying to use regex (JAVA) to extract the name attribute from the Field, and the actual value inside the Value node. Is this possible using regex?

I have the following regex that is close, but it doesn't stop at the first ending `</Field>` tag

```
\\<Field([^\\>]*)\\>(.+)\\</Field\\>
```

Comment: Why not xpath instead? Would make your life much easier.  Is each < Field> element a separate string?

Comment: Please look into using an XML parser, and read about xpath.  Using regex to parse XML is generally not a good idea.

Comment: the problem is, the string contains other data, and the XML may not be well-formed

Comment: It is not a good idea to use regex, but still if you are interested, you can check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241615/find-everything-between-two-xml-tags-with-regex

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the best idea that we do so using regular expressions here. However, if you wish, we can try adding optional capturing groups and collect the data that we want:

```
<field name="(.+?)"(.+\s*)?<value.+?>(.+?)<\/value>(\s*)?<\/field>
```

We can use a `i` flag here.

[image]

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "<field name=\"(.+?)\"(.+\\s*)?<value.+?>(.+?)<\\/value>(\\s*)?<\\/field>";
final String string = "<Field name=\"foo\" date=\"20170501\">\n"
     + "   <Value type=\"foo\">someVal</Value>\n"
     + "</Field>\n"
     + "<Field name=\"foo\" date=\"20170501\">\n"
     + "   <Value type=\"foo\">someVal</Value>\n"
     + "</Field>\n"
     + "<Field name=\"foo\" date=\"20170501\"><Value type=\"foo\">someVal</Value></Field>\n";
final String subst = "\\1: \\3";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
```

#### Demo

This snippet is just to show that how the capturing groups work:

```js
const regex = /<field name="(.+?)"(.+\s*)?<value.+?>(.+?)<\/value>(\s*)?<\/field>/gmi;
const str = `<Field name="foo" date="20170501">
   <Value type="foo">someVal</Value>
</Field>
<Field name="foo" date="20170501">
   <Value type="foo">someVal</Value>
</Field>
<Field name="foo" date="20170501"><Value type="foo">someVal</Value></Field>
`;
const subst = `$1: $3`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/MLEqMA/1).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) also helps to visualize the expressions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, regular expressions would not be suitable for this task, since it is less readable and efficient. But anyway...

**field.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Fields>
    <Field name="foo 1" date="20170501">
        <Value type="foo">someVal 1</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field name="foo 2" date="20170501">
        <Value type="foo">someVal 2</Value>
    </Field>
</Fields>
```

**Solution 1.: Regular Expression (*The ugly, but fun way...*)**

```java
try {
    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("path/to/fields/xml/file.xml"));
    String content = new String(encoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<field[\\s\\S]*?name=\"(?<gName>[\\s\\S]*?)\"[\\s\\S]*?>[\\s\\S]*?<value\\b[\\s\\S]*?>(?<gVal>[\\s\\S]*?)</value>[\\s\\S]*?</field>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE );
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);

    // while loop for each <Field> entry
    while(matcher.find()) {
        matcher.group("gName"); // named group 'gName' contains the value of name attribute
        matcher.group("gVal"); // named group 'gVal' contains the text content of the value tag
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Solution 2: `XPath` (*The right, but boring way...*)**

**Field class:**

```java
public class Field {
    private String name;
    private String value;

    // ... getter & setters ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Field { name: %s, value: %s }", this.name, this.value);
    }
}
```

**Boring class:**

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class Boring {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
      DocumentBuilder builder;
      Document doc = null;

      try {
          builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
          doc = builder.parse("path/to/fields/xml/file.xml");

          XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

          // Create XPath object
          XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

          List<Field> fields = getFields(doc, xpath);

          for (Field f : fields) {
            System.out.println(f);
          }

      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

  private static List<Field> getFields(Document doc, XPath xpath) {
      List<Field> list = new ArrayList<>();
      try {
          XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/Fields/*");

          NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
          for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
              Node fieldNode = nodes.item(i);
              NodeList fieldNodeChildNodes = fieldNode.getChildNodes();

              Field field = new Field();
              // set name
              field.setName(fieldNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue());

              for (int j = 0; j < fieldNodeChildNodes.getLength(); j++) {
                  if (fieldNodeChildNodes.item(j).getNodeName() == "Value") {
                      // set value
                      field.setValue(fieldNodeChildNodes.item(j).getTextContent());
                      break;
                  }
              }
              list.add(field);
          }
      } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return list;
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```sh
Field { name: foo 1, value: someVal 1 }
Field { name: foo 2, value: someVal 2 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When using XML, regular expressions are not exactly the way to go when searching through it, but rather you should use Xpath which is pretty much to solve the exact problem you are having. Regex can be used for this but I seriously would not recommend using it.

You can learn xpath in a few hours, here's a [link](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) to learning it.

Good luck