# How to retrieve data between XML tags in node.js

Tags: node.js, xml

I am trying to get data from XML tags and assign it a variable in node JS and here is what I tried.

```
 //Sample XML
let sampleXML = "<Response>
                   <Header>
                     <tag1>I am trying to get this</tag1>
                     <tag2>This one too</tag2>
                   </Header>
                   <Detail>
                     <tag1>XYZ</tag1>
                     <tag2>ABC</tag2>
                   </Detail>
              </Response>"




var betweenString = sampleXML.match(/<Header>([^<]*)<\/Header>/);

console.log('Between String:' + betweenString);
```

This gives me null in between string. Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: I tried  these two lines                                                                                               
  var betweenString = sampleXML.match(/<Header>([^<]*)<\/Header>/);

console.log('Between String:' + betweenString);

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it's probably safer and more precise than using regex (in case you have multiple tags of the same name in the xml doc.

```js
const { transform } = require('camaro')
let sampleXML = `<Response>
                   <Header>
                     <tag1>I am trying to get this</tag1>
                     <tag2>This one too</tag2>
                   </Header>
                   <Detail>
                     <tag1>XYZ</tag1>
                     <tag2>ABC</tag2>
                   </Detail>
              </Response>`




;(async function () {
    const template = {
        betweenString: 'raw(Response/Header)'
    }

    const result = await transform(sampleXML, template)
    console.log('Between String:' + result.betweenString)

})()
```

output

```
Between String:<Header>
        <tag1>I am trying to get this</tag1>
        <tag2>This one too</tag2>
</Header>
```

this works by parse the xml, get the node (via xpath - we specify where to get it `Response/Header`) and print the node text. however, in your case, you probably wants to remove the open and close `Header` tag after parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the fact that this question is specific to Node.js, it is a duplicate of [Find everything between two XML tags with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241615/find-everything-between-two-xml-tags-with-regex/13241658#13241658) -- and you should particularly read the answer that explains why processing XML using regular expressions is a really bad idea.