# Find xml tag between a certain tag with RegEx

Tags: regex, xml, xml-parsing, logstash-grok

I have log files that I wish to parse the xml with certain condition

a sample of the log file

```
<Text>
    ns:="https://www.example.com"
    <Error>
        <id>ex8359693589435834583985934583495</id>
        <ErrorItem>
            <id>slak;jdk;asjdklasjdklasjdfhkldj;sfjdsf</id>
            <code>404</code>
            <description>External>  failed messages multiple line of detials </description>
            <reference>/</reference>
        </ErrorItem>
    </Error>
    <InformationLog>
        <cccpInformation>
            <description>External>  failed messages multiple line of detials 2 </description>
            <Place>
                <id>988475748848758478545</id>
            </Place>
        </cccpInformation>
    </InformationLog>
</Text>
```

Basically, I only want to capture the `<description>` tag only in `<ErrorItem></ErrorItem>`, and nothing else.
and the logs also contain `description` tag on other level of the tag

But the post like [Find everything between two XML tags with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241615/find-everything-between-two-xml-tags-with-regex/74515809#74515809)

will only capture the tag next under/next to it.

I can achieve some basic matching using something like
`(?s)<ErrorItem>(.*?)<\/description>`

but it will select everything inside `<ErrorItem> </ErrorItem>`

Anyone can give me a hand here?

Comment: Parsing XML with regex is inherently a bad idea. Why not use a standard XML parser?

Comment: Yes, but it is the only way without changing the too much